# How to add a condition to a crystal report in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm working on a uni project and I need to use a crystal report to view this table in a form:
[image]

I don't want it to view all the records in that table, I want it to view the records where city = "KSA". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a Details Section to display each row of the table, and that you want to hide the entire row, you have to:

1. Right click on the Details section header
2. Select Section Expert
3. On the left, click on the concerned Details section
4. Go to the Common tab, and on the **Hide** option you should be able to open a Formula dialogue.

There, you can specify a little formula that when returning TRUE  will hide the section, and when returning FALSE, it will display. So, you should enter something like:

```
Not({MyTable.City} = 'KSA')
```

(Not really sure if that is the exact syntax).

Comment: sorry but Im using VB 2010, may I know where is -Right click on the Details section header??

Comment: I assumed that you were working on the Crystal Reports designer, so you should have something that looked like this --> http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/img/csharp-crystal-report-designer-window.GIF
Therefore, you right click on the "Section 3" header (actually you can go to the Section Expert by clicking on any section header).